# SharePoint Web Part 'The refresh token has expired or is invalid due to sign-in frequency checks by conditional access'

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, spfx

First off the background, we have a SharePoint Intranet which can be accessed via the browser, or accessed via the Viva Connections app in Microsoft Teams. On the Intranet homepage there is a custom webpart that utilises Graph API.

There are 3 ways to access this SharePoint homepage, 1. Browse to the SharePoint page, 2. Teams web client via Viva Connections app, or 3. Teams Desktop client via Viva Connections app.

The custom webpart opens perfectly fine in SharePoint and the Teams web client. However, when using the **Teams desktop client**, the custom webpart **does not** appear on the page.  When checking the errors, the following error is shown:

```
The refresh token has expired or is invalid due to sign-in frequency checks by conditional access
```

There is a workaround fix which is for the user to sign out and then back in to the Teams client.  This appears to resolve the issue, however this could be temporary as the refresh token most likely will expire again.

There is a conditional access policy in place with a sign-in frequency of 30 days, and a password policy to never expire.

Has anyone seen this issue before and point me in the right direction?  The browser works fine, so this is limited to Teams desktop client only.

Comment: When a user signs in to an application, a refresh token is issued which is used to refresh the access token when it expires. If the refresh token itself expires or becomes invalid, the user is required to sign in again to get a new refresh token. This is likely why signing out and back into the Teams client resolves the issue temporarily. However there doesn't seem to be any way to handle this in Desktop client. So, you might need to adjust the sign-in frequency in your conditional access policy.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by increasing the sign-in frequency on the conditional access policy